# Regular expression to match IRC nickname

Tags: regex, irc

How would I use a regular expression to match an IRC nickname? This is being done in Ruby if that makes a difference (it probably will, with the syntax of the regex, but who knows.)

EDIT: An IRC nickname can contain any letter, number, or any of the following characters: `<
-  [ ] \` `^ { }`

Comment: Ruby uses PCRE, doesn't it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924648/pcre-expression-for-irc-nicknames

Comment: What can and can't be in an IRC nickname? In what positions? What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: @codaddict: What do you mean? The rule is to match any IRC nickname.

Comment: @Satya: Not really, only certain characters are allowed in IRC nicknames. Which I edited my answer to include.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes: I have edited my answer to include this information, and as to what positions can they be in: they can be anywhere. And I really haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: By "any letter", I do you mean "any letter in the Latin alphabet"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
# If you are testing a single string
irc_nick_re = /\A[a-z_\-\[\]\\^{}|`][a-z0-9_\-\[\]\\^{}|`]*\z/i 

# If you are scanning them out of a larger string
irc_nick_re = /(?<=[^a-z_\-\[\]\\^{}|`])[a-z_\-\[\]\\^{}|`][a-z0-9_\-\[\]\\^{}|`]*/i
```

The above allows single-character names. If two characters are required, change the `*` to `+`. If three characters (or more) are required, change it to `{2,}`, where '2' is the minimum number of characters minus 1.

If there is a maximum number of characters (for example, EFNet only allows nicknames up to 9 characters lone, while Freenode allows nicks up to 16 characters long) then you can include that number (minus 1) after the comma. For example:

```
# Validate nicknames that are between 3 and 16 characters long (inclusive)
irc_nick_re = /\A[a-z_\-\[\]\\^{}|`][a-z0-9_\-\[\]\\^{}|`]{2,15}\z/i
```

Comment: I don't know of any popular IRC network which allows "<" in nicknames. IRCnet, FreeNode, Quakenet, OFTC, Undernet and EFnet all reject it. Also, you shouldn't match a digit at the beginning of the nickname, since no IRC network allows that either. Furthermore, you're missing "|", "`", and "_", which are allowed. And the "\d" should be "0-9" instead, since those are the only digits allowed, not any Unicode digit.

Comment: @Hinrik Great points! I was matching based on the OP's requirements, but not testing against real-world implementations. However, note that [`\d` does not match Unicode digits in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998713/scanning-for-unicode-numbers-in-a-string-with-d).