# Enforce exactly 8 digits for ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I use in my model following regular expression for getting a number that must to have a length 8. I do it this way:

> validates_uniqueness_of :my_number, :with => /^[0-9]{8}$/, :message => "error message"

But this doesn't works me, if I set into the input "hahaha", I will get the "error message", if I set there **123**, so I will get a success output, but that's wrong... I try to get a regular expression that will accepted always exact 8 digits...

Comment: You likely want a "validates" with both a regex *and* uniqueness.

Comment: Note that `[0-9]` is [exactly equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998713/scanning-for-unicode-numbers-in-a-string-with-d) to the (shorter and more-self-describing) `\d` in Ruby regex. See also [the official docs](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/re.rdoc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably:

```
validates_format_of :my_number, :with =>  /\A[0-9]{8}\Z/
validates_uniqueness_of :my_number
```

Comment: In Rails 3+ this is expressed as `validates :my_number, :uniqueness => true, :format => { :with => /.../ }` using the new [validation methods](http://omgbloglol.com/post/392895742/improved-validations-in-rails-3).

Answer (score 4):

Update: As [@tadman points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313352/89391)  in the comment, in Rails 3 you can [combine validators](http://omgbloglol.com/post/392895742/improved-validations-in-rails-3):

```
validates :my_number, :uniqueness => true, :format => { :with => /^[0-9]{8}$/ }
```

---

Using old-style validation:

[`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000086) does not accept a `with` option, just [`validates_format_of`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000087) does. So you might try:

```
validates_format_of :my_number, :with => /^[0-9]{8}$/, \
    :message => "8 digits, please."
```

To validate uniqueness you might want to add another constraint.